# React state not getting updated in function call

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple function where I'm trying to update state. The state is not getting updated when the function is called.

Clicking on the button the function getCityWeather will be called.
I have also provided the sandbox url below to play around with it.

```
export class AppMain extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      weather: "",
      query: "",
      countryQuery: "IN",
      currentCity: "Search a town...",
      currentDate: new Date().setHours(23, 59, 59, 0) / 1000,
      forecast: ""
    };
  }

  getCityWeather = () => {
    console.log(this.state.query);
   //ABOVE STATEMENT NOT GETTING LOGGED WITH UPDATED TEXT
  };

  handleCityChange = e => {
    //BELOW STATEMENT IS EXECUTING FINE
    console.log("city change called");
    this.setState({ query: e.target.value }, this.getCityWeather);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <WeatherFilter handleCityChange={this.handleCityChange} />
        <div />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Below is the sandbox url, Not sure the reason behind the state not getting updated.

https://codesandbox.io/s/weather-report-rgu7y-rgu7y

Is there a hack to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Put onchange on input and for submitting create new method.

```
export class WeatherFilter extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter City Name" onChange={this.props.handleCityChange}/>
        <button onClick={this.props.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the onChange event handler on the input itself in order to access e.target.value

```
<input onChange={this.props.handleCityChange} type="text" placeholder="Enter City Name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems one is not handling the `onChange` on text box or not capturing the value in `input text box`. Other is log the state after update. In order to log the state after update pass callback as second parameter to `this.setState` or call the function which logs the state in `componentDidUpdate`

`weatherFilter.js`

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export class WeatherFilter extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter City Name"
          onChange={this.props.handleCityChange}
        />
        <button onClick={this.props.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

to pass callback as second param

```
handleSubmit = e => {
    this.setState({ query: this.state.queryval },()=>this.getCityWeather());
  };
```

or

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    this.getCityWeather();
   }
```

[Fixed sandbox code](https://codesandbox.io/s/weather-report-rgu7y-lgm56)